# HighStock - how show & format tooltip for more than 1 series scatter chart?

Tags: highcharts

No problem doing this with Area chart, but can't find a way to do it for scatter charts. Used http://jsfiddle.net/uZXPR/1/ as a starting point but it's only 1 series and has no special formatting. I've tried numerous stabs in the dark but no luck so far. I could submit all those failed attempts here but I think it'd be quicker to start from http://jsfiddle.net/uZXPR/1/ and just add what's needed.

There are some indications that others are having problems with multiple series scatter chart tooltips, but of course particulars are different in every case.

Here's a snippet of how I do it with Area chart (the gNs.format* functions are just local homegrown formatting routines):

```
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<b>' + gNs.formatDate(new Date(this.x), '%Y-%M-%d') + '</b>';
                $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                    s +='<br/>' + 
                        '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + '</span>' + 
                        ': ' +
                        gNs.formatSeconds2HMS(point.y);                     });
                return s;
            },
            shared: true          
        },
```

Comment: The problem is that [`shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.shared) option for tooltip doesn't work with scatter, so you can't use two scatter series in one tooltip, just check out docs. I would advice to change from scatter series, to line series and just set `lineWidth: 0` for them.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I missed that in the docs. Tried line series with lineWidth:0 and it sort of works except you can't see any datapoints unless you're moving the mouse across the chart. Is there any way to have all datapoints appear just as they would if it were a scatter chart?

Comment: Sure, just enable markers, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.marker.enabled).

Comment: Perfect! Turns out I had markers lineWidth: 1 but not explicitly enabled.